# Assertion Error While Testing the Pipeline Apache Beam

Tags: unit-testing, apache-beam

While testing the pipeline I got this error even the error log shows that the objects are equal:

```
    public void testGenerateUserPageViews() throws Exception{
        final PCollection<SessionModel> input = p.apply(Create.of(SESSION_MODEL));
        final PCollection<UserPageViews> output = input.apply(ParDo.of(new GenerateUserPageViews()));
        PAssert.that(output).containsInAnyOrder(USER_PAGEVIEWS);
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: ParDo(GenerateUserPageViews)/ParMultiDo(GenerateUserPageViews).output: 
Expected: iterable over [<com.userprofile.models.UserPageViews@e1688b19>] in any order
     but: Not matched: <com.userprofile.models.UserPageViews@e1688b19>

    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$PAssertionSite.capture(PAssert.java:174)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert.that(PAssert.java:416)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert.that(PAssert.java:408)
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I replace String variable with "" value in place of null. But I still don't understand why the object reference are the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `com.userprofile.models.UserPageViews` does not have a fully implemented `equals` or `hashCode` method.

Comment: Already implemented

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue where my objects looked the same, but the assertion failed. This was because the equals() method returned false for those objects. A solution is to check each field of your object one by one or to make the problematic field null if equals() fails because of it.

**Option 1**: Assert on Individual Fields

```
data class MyObject(
    val field1: String,
    val field2: Exception? //field that returns false on equals()
)


@Test
fun option1() {
    val pCollectionActual: PCollection<MyObject> = /** your actual call here */
    val expectedElement = MyObject(field1 = "field1", field2 = Exception())

    PAssert.that(pCollectionActual).satisfies { collection ->
        Iterators.size(collection.iterator()) shouldBe 1
        val iterator = collection.iterator()
        val actualElement = iterator.next()
        actualElement.field1 shouldBe expectedElement.field1
        actualElement.field2 shouldBe expectedElement.field2
        iterator.hasNext() shouldBe false
        null
    }
    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()
}
```

**Option 2**: Set Non-Matching Fields to Null

```
@Test
fun option2() {
    val pCollectionActual: PCollection<MyObject> = /** actual call here */
    val element = MyObject(field1 = "field1", field2 = null)
    val expectedList: List<MyObject> = listOf(element)

    PAssert.that(pCollectionActual).containsInAnyOrder(expectedList)

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()
}
```